# Play Framework 2.1 application mounted as an IntelliJ Module

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Known is the command to create IntelliJ files needed for a Play application:

```
play idea with-sources=yes
```

This generates two folders:

- `.idea` (containing `libraries.xml`)
- `.idea_modules`

Most of tutorials or simple article on the net explain how to mount the app as an IntelliJ **Project**.

However, I want to mount it as a **Module** (as part of an existing project so), thus I've just used the `.idea_modules` file.

I can't imagine me setting ALL dependencies (more than 100...) manually...

How to deal with the libraries (dependencies)? Indeed, `libraries.xml` is used in `.idea` file and typically used when someone want to mount the app as an entire Project.

To put in a nutshell, is there an efficient way to set up a Play app in IntelliJ as a simple Module including automatically all needed dependencies?

It would be great if IntelliJ could implement an SBT feature like the one for Maven in order to import dependencies automatically.

Comment: Indeed, having first class support for sbt is very desirable (at least for 93 of us) and we are getting closer as there is a preview available now. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-2472

Comment: @Georg Engel Intereresting :) Thanks!